# Discord.js slash command role/channel options

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm using Discord.js to write a bot with a number of helpful commands, however I can't seem to find anywhere on either Discord's API docs or Discord.js' docs that lists an example of the json structure for a slash command's role and channel options. I have the commands registering properly, but don't know what sort of data those interactions give me.

TL;DR: what data is returned when I call the following:

```js
interaction.options.getChannel("channelOptionName")
//and
interaction.options.getRole("roleOptionName")
```

I'm not able to run any code in any reasonable amount of time, so I'm not able to just console.log it and go from there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A [Role Object](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions#:~:text=Role%20Object,(guild)%20and%20channel%20context.) is returned for `.getRole`.

A [Channel Object](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel) is returned for `.getChannel`.